# Ping a server from VB.net via a specific proxy

Tags: .net, vb.net, proxy, network-programming, ping

I know that you can easily send a ping request and receive a boolean return type in .NET, using something like:

`If My.Computer.Network.Ping(addressToPing_str, pingTimeOutMS_int) Then

    MessageBox.Show("Ping successful")

End If`

But this appears to use the proxy that it set globally for windows (Looks like it uses the same setting that internet explorer uses.)

What i want to do is specify my own IP and port to use as a proxy, instead of using the windows global value or whatever it is...

There will be multiple applications running at once, and indeed multiple pings at once, as my application checks multiple servers in parallell. Therefore, changing the global value, sending a ping, then setting it back is not an option.

So my question is - Is there any alternate method of sending a ping request that will also allow me to specify what proxy server I want to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure ICMP traffic goes through a HTTP proxy on port 80. Do some extra research on your exact network configuration. I'm sure you'll find ICMP operates on its own port and will not go through a HTTP proxy.

Comment: if so, then how would you suggest checking the status of a proxy? I can of course ping the proxy server itself, but that just means that the proxy server is up, not that i can actually connect to a site through it...    (Basically, if i could set IE up to use said proxy, and the successfully load google, i want a "true" response, but if not i want "false")

Comment: So really your trying to test HTTP proxies for valid connections to the internet? That is quite simple in .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a Web Service in a location visible to all of the nodes you want to ping. Make a method on the webservice called `Public Function Ping(Byval ipAddress As String) As Int32`

Then in your application consume the Web Service and invoke the `Async` methods that the code generates when you first consume the Web Service. The `Async` methods allow for some degree of this 'parallellization' that you speak of.

Invoke the `PingAsync` with a callback.

The Web Service acts as your 'Proxy' and will be accessible via HTTP. You can then invoke a Ping even on a client with ICMP traffic blocked.

**Edit:**

If you just want to test a HTTP proxy for a valid connection you can use the `WebRequest`/`WebClient` classes and download a small file on a remote computer.

Information is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s8th0s1.aspx and a console example is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.proxy.aspx

`WebRequest.Proxy` will allow you to specify the HTTP proxy and the credentials passed. You could then load say http://www.whatismyip.org/ and check to see if you get a response. If you get a response then your HTTP proxy is working.

Comment: thanks - I think WebRequest with the Proxy property might be just what i need

Answer (score 0):

What about using P/Invoke to call the [ICMP](http://www.sockets.com/ms_icmp.htm) library / [IcmpSendEcho](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/icmp.icmpsendecho) directly?

Comment: In most corporate networks internet ICMP traffic is either blocked, trapped by a proxy or disabled.